# MariaDB: Match requests with work performed where total > 0 using a case

Tags: datetime, mariadb, case

I have a request table and a work table. For request type 1, 2, 4, or 5 I need to sum the work performed of type 6 or 7 where 6 represents effectively +1 and 7 represents -1. Exclude any requests where the request's work sum is <=0 or work were done before the most recent request.

The query details are:

- Find requests type in (1, 2, 4, 5) by createDate.
- For each request date found, sum work type in (6, 7) as +1 or -1 until the next request createDate.
- Output any requests work sum > 0 before the next request.

The sample tables:

```
create table request
(
    Id             bigint not null,
    userId         bigint,
    type           bigint not null,
    creationDate   timestamp not null
);
create table work
(
    Id             bigint not null,
    type           bigint not null,
    creationDate   timestamp not null
);
```

The sample data:

```
insert into request (Id, userId, type, creationDate)
values  (4, 45, 2, '2022-12-12 11:02:17'),
        (9, 64, 2, '2022-12-12 01:01:18'),
        (2, 92, 2, '2022-12-11 21:36:36'),
        (2, 21, 2, '2022-12-11 21:25:54'),
        (1, 3, 2, '2022-12-11 21:13:58'),
        (7, 243, 2, '2022-12-11 21:04:05'),
        (8, 24, 2, '2022-12-11 21:01:23');
insert into work (Id, type, creationDate)
values  (3, 7, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (6, 7, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (11, 7, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (6, 7, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (1, 6, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (2, 6, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (11, 7, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (5, 7, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (1, 6, '2022-12-11 00:00:00'),
        (11, 7, '2022-12-12 00:00:00'),
        (4, 6, '2022-12-12 00:00:00'),
        (8, 7, '2022-12-12 00:00:00');
```

The attempted query:

```
select id, sum(total), type, creationDate from (
  select id, 0 as total, type, creationDate from request
  union
  select id, case type when 6 then 1 when 7 then -1 end as total, type, creationDate from work
) a where total > 0 group by id
```

This takes too long on live data, but works on small sets [like this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/X9TCf-bo).

There is a challenge in the data, the timestamp for requests includes the time, but the work only has date with no timestamp.

The fiddle reports:

| id | sum(total) | type | creationDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 2022-12-11 00:00:00 |
| 2 | 1 | 6 | 2022-12-11 00:00:00 |
| 4 | 1 | 6 | 2022-12-13 00:00:00 |

However both 1 and 2 are invalidated because the timestamp of the request is technically greater than the work. The expected output should be:

| id | sum(total) | type | creationDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 1 | 6 | 2022-12-13 00:00:00 |

For id = 4, the work had the date of 2022-12-13 00:00:00 and the request was timestamped 2022-12-12 11:02:17.

Comment: If you're suming all the work types for a request, you can produce a query like ```SELECT r.id, SUM(CASE WHEN w.type = 7 THEN -1 WHEN w.type = 6 THEN 1 END) AS worksum 
  FROM request AS r 
  JOIN work AS w
    ON  w.id = r.id AND r.CreationDate <= w.creationdate
GROUP BY r.id
HAVING worksum >= 0``` Is that what you're looking to do? Or are you looking to sum all the work types between requests?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Go ahead and answer please. I think that works. I'll test on full live data tonight. So if you have an answer in time, I can award the bounty.

Comment: One small addition to what @OluwafemiSule posted - you also need to include the requirement types in the condition (see first bullet of the requirements - `Find requests type in (1, 2, 4, 5) by createDate.`).

Answer (score 1):

One way to accomplish this is to use a subquery to join the two tables together and then group the results

Here's an example:

```
SELECT r.Id, SUM(CASE w.type WHEN 6 THEN 1 WHEN 7 THEN -1 END) as total, r.type, r.creationDate
FROM request r
JOIN (
  SELECT Id, type, creationDate
  FROM work
  WHERE type IN (6,7)
) w ON w.creationDate >= r.creationDate
WHERE r.type IN (1,2,4,5)
GROUP BY r.Id, r.type, r.creationDate
HAVING total > 0
```